# cannot find -libsubstrate-dvm -libsubstrate

Tags: android, hook, native

I got a problem in android.mk.It always show me that cannot find -lsubstrate-dvm and -lsubstrate. I don't know what it is? Could someone tell me how to solve this problem ? Here is the logcat:

```
Android NDK:non-system libraries in linker flags: -libsubstrate-dvm -libsubstrate
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
cannot find -libsubstrate-dvm
cannot find -libsubstrate
```

Here is the android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := substrate
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsubstrate.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := substrate-dvm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsubstrate-dvm.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := cydiasubstrate.cy
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cydiasubstrate.cy.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -lsubstrate-dvm -lsubstrate -lz
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

substrate-dvm is the name of the module being built, it relies on a prebuild library, not on sources, so you should look for libsubstrate-dvm.so

You could follow the following link for further help:
https://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2014/12/16/hooking-non-public-methods-with-the-ndk-using-mobile-substra.html

> to include the Substrate libraries. The easiest way to
>   do this is to navigate to the ‘/sdk/extras/saurikit/cydia_substrate/’
>   directory and copy ‘substrate.h’ and navigate to the
>   ‘/sdk/extras/saurikit/cydia_substrate/lib//’ directory and copy
>   ‘libsubstrate-dvm.so’ file into the jni folder of the project.